# English pronunciation of "charade" as in Pink Floyd song Pigs

Tags: pronunciation, accent

I was recently listening to the Pink Floyd song "Pigs (Three different ones)" and a line in the chorus goes,

> Ha ha, charade you are!

In the context of the song I am nearly sure that the word `charade` is intended to mean something or someone that is a fake.  What interests me is the way that the word is pronounced.

It is being pronounced `Sha-r-ahhh-d` (Not sure how to convey a long `ah` accent but that is the intent.  As an American, I have only ever heard this word pronounced more like `Sha-r-AID`.

My question is, is there a single correct pronunciation of the word, or is this simply pronounced differently in England as compared to America (US, Canada)?  Or... is this simply just a poetic pronunciation of the word in the song for effect and uniqueness?

Comment: In IPA, you mean Brit. /ʃəˈrɑːd/ and U.S. /ʃəˈreɪd/.

Comment: @tchrist I don't even know what kind of voodoo unicode magic you pulled to string those characters together but it looks completely foreign to me. It would be easier to read cryllic I would think :)

Comment: It’s nothing fancier than the selfsame trick everyone always used to pull in any other text: you find a web page that has it, apply murine snarf-n-barf to the problem, and *voilà* all is well. The *International Phonetic Alphabet* is ***the*** standard phonetic notation, and you should always use it for illustrating pronunciations. It’s what the best dictionaries use, too. Failing that, you can sometimes approximate it by using rhyming words, but that is an error-prone process subject to regional interpretation. But these spelt-out faux-phonetic spellings never work.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Don't be misled by the preponderance of Americans on ELU. Per my comment to mgb's misleading answer, Waters sings *Sha-r-ahhh-d* (IPA /ʃəˈrɑːd/) because that's how Brits always say the word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is yet another French-derived word where using oxytonic stress sounds variously highbrow, bourgeois, educated, or pretentious if it differs from one’s native accent. Others are *homage* /ˈhɒmɪdʒ/ vs  /oʊˈmɑʒ/, *montage* /ˈmɒntɑːʒ/ vs /mɑnˈtɑʒ/, and of course *garage* /ˈgærɑːʒ/ vs /ˈgærɪdʒ/. Yet it is always *rummage* /ˈrʌmɪdʒ/ but *mirage* /mᵻˈrɑːʒ/. Sometimes the OED marks unassimilated words in the original, like *enfleurage*  /ɑ̃flœrɑːʒ/, without any stress at all. You’d think they’re all destined to have their stress shifted backwards, as in *camouflage* /ˈkæmɵflɑːʒ/.

Comment: @tchrist: I think you get more of these quirky variations in American because historically the country has always been less densely populated. People guess pronunciation from the written form, and if they live in some isolated community their version might just take off. Brits have more variability in total, because we have so many dialectal differences, but for straightforward issues like this where historical origin/written form may mislead, it seems we're less susceptible.

Comment: @tchrist et al. You guys are all wrong! It's /ʃa.ʁad/ of course. If you're standing on this side of the [English] Channel I mean. +1 for the question and many very insightful/witty comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From (2009 copy) OED:

> **charade** (ʃəˈrɑːd)
>
> A kind of riddle, in which each syllable of the word to be guessed, and sometimes the word itself also, is enigmatically described, or (more recently) dramatically represented (acted charade). Extended also to similar sportive trials of skill, as dumb charades, numbered charades, etc.

Not being a subscriber, I can't access the latest online version of OED, which *may* mention the US pronunciation /ʃəˈreɪd/ ("shar-aid"). But that doesn't appear at all in my copy, and I've never heard Brits say anything other than (ʃəˈrɑːd) ("shar-ard").

Comment: 'ard'?  two 'r' sounds?

Comment: @cornbread ninja: Yawn. I'm *British* - we don't have your American Rhotic "r"!

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OED3 has not yet updated its *charade* entry, so what you have there is the same as the online version. However, it’s not quite fair to say that *British* accents are necessarily non-rhotic. Please [study this marvellous UK page](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/) on accents for how many places in Britain proper actually *are* rhotic. You are of course correct though if you meant that **RP**, and more loosely BBC or Home Counties, English is non-rhotic. For bonus points, can you tell me why (and perhaps whether) we must write ***non-rhotic*** rather than ***arrhotic***? 

Comment: @tchrist: Well, in light of some of your earlier comments, you probably don't approve of me attempting any kind of phonetic representation apart from IPA anyway. I was only trying to be helpful to OP, who said he didn't find it easy to read. I didn't expect the Spanish Inquisition!

Comment: @tchrist _Arrhotic_ is too easily confused with _erotic_, which would be a point of contention with many accents.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Noooobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!" (Sorry, I couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: In standard IPA phonetics, that’s  Brit.  **/ʃəˈrɑːd/** and U.S.  **/ʃəˈreɪd/**.

Merriam-Webster advises that both pronunciations are correct:

> ### [cha·rade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charade)
>
> noun \shə-ˈrād, -ˈräd\

and also states its origins as French:

> French, from Occitan charrado chat, from charrá to chat, chatter

Comment: Thanks, that is informative.  This still doesn't answer why I never hear Americans pronounce it in another way however.  Is this just coincidence?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm glad we don't say 'fah-sayd' instead of 'fah-sahd'.  :)

Comment: Interesting that it is a French derived word meaning "chat". Does this imply that the English word was termed with the assumption that chatterboxes are fake or false?  Sounds like a different question...

Comment: @cornbreadninja That’s why it must always be spelt *façade*, lest it be taken for a *fuckade*.

Comment: @tchrist That sounds like quite the refreshing beverage.

Answer (score 0):

In BE the short A (Sha-r-AID) version is more common, the Floyd just needed to use the alternate to make the line scan.

edit: After consultation with *she who must be obeyed* (British model) - I am informed that sha-rard (as in Pink Floyd's song) is the 'normal' pronunciation and I am a *thick northerner*

Comment: It doesn't fit the meter fine with the 'AID' pronunciation?

Comment: -1: I don't know why you call *AID* the "short" version - if anything I'd say being a diphthong it's longer than **ɑː** (rhymes with *"last"*), which is the **standard** British pronunciation (the *only* one given in my OED). In short, Floyd didn't "do" anything to make it scan (not that scansion would be affected by this anyway) - Roger Waters being British, he just sings the word the same way any Brit would.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I wouldn't say shar-ard was the normal BE pronunciation (unless you are doing extreme RP). The line IIRC is har-har, sha-rard you are.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Great comment and insightful! If you change this to an answer I will accept it.  The legitimacy of the OED is hard to dispute.

Comment: My accent is "Estuary English", and I went to a secondary modern school, so I certainly don't think I'm likely to be swayed by RP. Waters was a bit more "upmarket", having gone to a grammar school. But like me, his father was a miner, so I account him to be of "peasant stock" like myself. But I'm pretty sure even the Royal Family play /ʃəˈrɑːdz/ after Christmas dinner, not /ʃəˈreɪdz/ (unless they have Americans visiting, who might not otherwise understand what game they were supposed to be playing! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Mick Jagger notwithstanding?

Comment: @cornbread ninja: Jagger actually *exaggerates* his "Sarf London" accent, so I doubt he'd be copying the American pronunciation of "charade". But you never know - some of these global jet-setters pick up all sorts of weird speech variations.